# Filtering DataFrame Index through Array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a sample dataframe `df` and an array`n`as shown below.  I want to filter based on the array values which are in index. The output dataframe is shown below as well.  I have tried `Out = df[df.index == n]` and `Out = df.loc[df.index == n ]` which is not working giving an error `Lengths must match to compare`. Can anyone help me in solving this.

df = 

        `Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2007-06-18  0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 1591888
1   2007-06-29  0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 88440
2   2007-06-20  0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 3538
3   2007-06-21  0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 3550
4   2007-06-22  0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 670
6   2007-06-18  0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 1591888
7   2007-06-29  0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 88440
8   2007-06-20  0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 3538
9   2007-06-21  0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 3550
10  2007-06-22  0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 0.34713 670`

array([     0,      1,      2, 3])

Out  = 

        `Date    Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume
0   2007-06-18  0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 0.33979 1591888
1   2007-06-29  0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 0.33074 88440
2   2007-06-20  0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 0.33526 3538
3   2007-06-21  0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 0.32113 3550`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
out = df[df.index.isin(n)]
```

Comment: what if there is  DateTime Index and my array is as shown above. Is there anyway to filter it on the basis of row number of array ? . Here the array number are row numbers

Comment: Sure - if the index is a datetime rather than integers, you can just use `df.loc[n]` .

Comment: Thanks! but that is giving me the `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` error

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions do not work because you are trying to compare the equality value of your short array `n` and df.index. You can use [pandas fancy-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) to get your solution. The following will work fine if `n` is a `np.array`.

```
df.loc[n]
```